# Trying to find an animated TV series about giants and humans who turn into jets and a giant robot

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

I was very young when I saw this show so the details might little off. Back in the mid-2000s, I watched this animated show with giants and humans, and I believe there were fighter jets the humans flew and then turned into giant robots. I know the plot is kinda centered around this one kid who either just graduated or was a cadet.

Comment: Back in the 2000s, all TV shows were about people turning into fighter-jets. Ah, those were simpler times.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what were the names of the characters? What did the giant robot look like? Who or what were they fighting?

Comment: I want to say Titan Maximum. Warning: NSFW (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87QfgABXxu0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jets transforming into robots and fighting against giants make me think of *Macross* ([*Super Dimension Fortress Macross*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Dimension_Fortress_Macross), also known as the first part of [*Robotech*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech) in some parts of the world):

- the main character is a young pilot that gets aboard a transforming jet during an alien attack on Earth
- the aliens look like gigantic humanoids

There are several series and movies, dating from the mid 80s, so maybe you happened to look at a rerun.

Comment: thank you so much it ended up being robotech